# Java program putting 2 char and space in pyramid pattern

Tags: java

I tried making a java program using 2 char with a space in pyramid pattern. I'm stuck halfway because i want to display the variable b but i dont know where to put and the result is it always display 1 char only. This is only for references for my upcoming exams. Little help is much appreciated.

Here's my code:

```
public static void main (String[]args){
   Scanner in =new Scanner(System.in);

   int rows;
   char a, b;

   System.out.print("Enter how many rows");
   rows = in.nextInt();
   System.out.print("Enter 1st char");
   a=in.next().charAt(0);
   System.out.print("Enter 2nd char");
   b=in.next().charAt(0);

   for (int r=2;r<=rows;r++)
   {
      for (int c=1;c<=r;c++) 
      {
         if (c==r)
         {
         System.out.print(a);
         }
         else
         {
         System.out.print(" ");
         }
      }
      System.out.println();
  }

}
```

The Output i want to display should be like this:

```
 *

   #

      *

        #

           *
```

And so on....

Thanks in advance guys. Badly need it because i didn't quite understand.

Comment: 1) fix your indentation 2) you never use the variable `b` 3) search for how to print a pyramid in java

Comment: Thank you, i fix my indentation. And change my question about the variable b. I did a research about pyramid in java but i can't find what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this in your loop

```
        if (c == r) {
          if (r % 2 == 0)
            System.out.print(a);
          else
            System.out.print(b);
        }
```

instead of

```
         if (c==r)
         {
         System.out.print(a);
         }
```

Simple math - you want every even row to be a and every odd row to be b, so you just check if row is odd or even.

And change

```
for (int r = 2; r <= rows; r++)
```

to

```
for (int r = 1; r <= rows; r++)
```

Output from my snippet:

```
Enter how many rows5
Enter 1st char*
Enter 2nd char#
#
 *
  #
   *
    #
```

Comment: you beat me by seconds

Comment: Yes, that's it! Thank you very much. That's where i'm really confused, about how to put the even row to be a and odd row to be b.

Comment: @ScaryWombat happens to me every time i want to answer :D

Comment: @Fritz No problem, glad to help you :)

Comment: I guess the polite thing to do then is just to upvote ;-)